# Error while generating TFS 2010 build using defaultTemplate.xaml in getworkspace method

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have define a topology where in TFS server and the TFS build services(Controller and the Agent) are defined in different machines, to test this topology I have created a sample Asp.net web application and used the defaultTemplate.xaml to define the build definition. However every time I run the build I get this error:

> 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfUndo+TfUndoCore.RunCommand(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.VersionControlScope,
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace,
> System.String, System.String)' to access method
> 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Undo(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ItemSpec[],
> Boolean, Boolean, System.String[])' failed.

I have tried deleting all the workspaces that are present in the build agent belonging to the administrator account, but is of no avail, I have also made sure that the user running the build has appropriate permissions.

Comment: You said that you tried delete all the workspaces on the build agent belonging to the Administrator account. Are you running the build service as Admin? It defaults to the Network Service account.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I have started getting the same error. I have raised a bug with Microsoft at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761363/tfs-build-get-workspace-step-fails-with-inscrutable-inter-method-access-error

Answer (score 0):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/749272/build-process-compiler-error-due-to-client-version

killing the workspaces works for this error
but note you have to open a solution before opening a template or you will get strange ambiguous errors like ibuilddetail missing ect.

bug is still open and this error shows up in TFS 2012 as well.